# CompressionType.LZ4 - Could not initialize class org.apache.kafka.common.record.KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

## Update

To provide some context - the Kafka topic is enabled with LZ4 compression.

When the compression type is recognized, the [`CompressionType` enum](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/6c806430093c152b916d8e8f1fa542980c03a181/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/record/CompressionType.java#L98-L117) tries to associate `LZ4` with the `KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream` which it could find for some reason during runtime.

```java
@Override
public InputStream wrapForInput(ByteBuffer inputBuffer, byte messageVersion, BufferSupplier decompressionBufferSupplier) {
    try {
        return new KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream(inputBuffer, decompressionBufferSupplier,
                                            messageVersion == RecordBatch.MAGIC_VALUE_V0);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new KafkaException(e);
    }
}
```

## Original Post

I have a JAR contains a Flink job to consume records from Kafka.

After submitting the JAR file to Flink, the task manager says that `KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream` class is missing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: SplitFetcher thread 0 received unexpected exception while polling the records
  at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:150)
  at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.run(SplitFetcher.java:105)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Received exception when fetching the next record from flight-cache-3. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1553)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1374)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:676)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:631)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1313)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1240)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)
  at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaPartitionSplitReader.fetch(KafkaPartitionSplitReader.java:113)
  at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.FetchTask.run(FetchTask.java:58)
  at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:142)
  ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.kafka.common.record.KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream
  at org.apache.kafka.common.record.CompressionType$4.wrapForInput(CompressionType.java:113)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch.compressedIterator(DefaultRecordBatch.java:261)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch.streamingIterator(DefaultRecordBatch.java:346)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.nextFetchedRecord(Fetcher.java:1496)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1533)
  ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.kafka.common.record.KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream
  at org.apache.kafka.common.record.CompressionType$4.wrapForInput(CompressionType.java:110)
  ... 19 more
```

I unzipped the JAR file to a folder and found that the class does exist:

```sh
$ ls -l org/apache/kafka/common/record/KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 wxh wxh 6489 Mar  2  2020 org/apache/kafka/common/record/KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream.class
```

I can also confirm `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.4.1` that contains the class does exist in the dependency tree.

```
+- org.apache.flink:flink-core:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  +- org.apache.flink:flink-annotations:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  +- org.apache.flink:flink-metrics-core:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-asm-7:jar:7.1-14.0:compile
|  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
|  +- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.24.0:compile
|  |  +- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:compile
|  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
|  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
|  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.21:compile
|  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-guava:jar:30.1.1-jre-14.0:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.15:compile
|  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
|  \- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-force-shading:jar:14.0:compile
+- org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.11:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  +- org.apache.flink:flink-runtime:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-rpc-core:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-rpc-akka-loader:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-queryable-state-client-java:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-hadoop-fs:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-netty:jar:4.1.65.Final-14.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-jackson:jar:2.12.4-14.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-zookeeper-3:jar:3.4.14-14.0:compile
|  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
|  |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.8.3:compile
|  |  \- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.8.0:compile
|  +- org.apache.flink:flink-optimizer:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  +- org.apache.flink:flink-java:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.5:compile
|  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.3.1:compile
|  \- org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.11:jar:1.14.0:compile
|     \- org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.11:jar:1.14.0:compile
|        +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.12:compile
|        +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.12:compile
|        +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.11.12:compile
|        |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:jar:1.0.5:compile
|        |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.0.4:compile
|        \- com.twitter:chill_2.11:jar:0.7.6:compile
|           \- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.7.6:compile
+- org.apache.flink:flink-connector-files:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  +- org.apache.flink:flink-file-sink-common:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  \- org.apache.flink:flink-connector-base:jar:1.14.0:compile
+- org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kafka_2.11:jar:1.14.0:compile
|  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.4.1:compile    # <--- IT DOES EXISTS
|     \- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.4.3-1:compile
+- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.22:provided
```

Anyone has any experience with this strange issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out LZ4Factory loads `net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4*Compressor/Decompressor` classes [via reflection](https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java/blob/master/src/java/net/jpountz/lz4/LZ4Factory.java#L175-L182), while `maven-shade-plugin` has `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` which removes all classes that are not directly referenced, e.g. via reflection.

Therefore, when [KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.7.2/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/record/KafkaLZ4BlockInputStream.java#L50) tries to access one of these classes via `LZ4Factory` during construction, it fails.

Setting `<minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>` solved it.